# JUnit - Oracle Database and StaleConnections

Tags: oracle, junit

I was wondering is there any way in Java to force a stale connection?

We have some logic that determines if a `sqlexception` received is actually a Stale Connection - if it is we try and reconnect to the database.

I could not find any objects that could be mocked (using EasyMock or Powermock) in order to similulate a stale connection so I was there any properties we can set on the connection cache to expire a connection?